# Targeting IE8 in CSS (less)?

Tags: css, less

Here's my CSS:

```
.lt-ie8{
    body{
        display:none!important;
    }
}
```

Here is my HTML:

```
<!--[if lt IE 7]>      <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class="no-js"> <!--<![endif]-->
<head>
```

The CSS doesn't appear to target IE7 correctly, does anyone know where I'm going wrong?

Comment: You need a space between `none` and `important`

Comment: Your question is confusing - are you targeting IE8 or IE7?

Comment: @Cody Guldner: IE has no problem with leaving out the space, and neither is it invalid to do so.

Comment: @beans: Did you fix your problem? If you did, please post your answer here.

Answer (score 1):

That worked perfectly for me.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
        .test{
            background: green;
            height: 100px;
            width: 100px;
        }
    </style>
    <!--[if lt IE 7]>      <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7"> <![endif]-->
    <!--[if IE 7]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8">
        <style type='text/css'>
            .test{
                background: red;
            }
        </style>
    <![endif]-->
    <!--[if IE 8]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9"> <![endif]-->
    <!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class="no-js"> <!--<![endif]-->

</head>
<body>
    <div class="test"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you checked whether the conditional css is applying or not on [IE Developer Toolbar](http://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=18359)?

Comment: That's why there is class 'lt-ie8', it should override any previous body statements if the 'html' tag is properly set for the specific browser.

Answer (score 0):

IE7 won't let you hide the body tag. A solution would be to create a wrapper div and hide that instead. I've encountered this before, but I'm not sure of the reason.

```
<html>
<!--[if IE 7]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class="no-js"> <!--<![endif]-->
<head>
    <style>
        .lt-ie8 div{ display: none !important;}
        body, html{width: 100%; height: 100%;}
        div {background-color: red; width: 100%; height: 100%;}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div></div>
</body>
</html>
```